# Динамический перевод приложения на языке С#

Tags: c#, wpf

Как сделать  динамический перевод приложения на С# WPF, что бы прям в приложении менялся язык с русского на английский и обратно. Какой самый правильный способ? и есть ли его пример? В идеале конечно привести ссылки на проекты в github на локализованные приложения. А там сам уже разберусь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я делал как-то следующим образом.

1. Все локализуемые строки кладутся в `ResourceDictionary`. Ссылки на них в XAML оформляются через `DynamicResource`.
2. Сам `ResourceDictionary` выгружается в satellite assembly.
3. Satellite assembly для других языков создаются через майкрософтовский LocBaml ([[1]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771568%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), [[2]](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17334/Localizing-WPF-Applications-using-Locbaml)).
4. Этого уже достаточно для правильной локализации при старте приложения. Для локализации на лету необходим следующий трюк: при переключении языка

   - меняем `CurrentCulture` и `CurrentUICulture` UI-потока (если их несколько, то каждого из них).
   - перечитываем все локализационные `ResourceDictionary`, для этого удаляем их из того места, где они были подключены, и снова добавляем. (Или в обратном порядке, чтобы не было момента, когда нет локализации.)

Проблема, которую приходится при этом решать — составные строки (например: `You can use free version {0} till activation is needed`, где `{0}` раскрывается в `2 days` или там `3 weeks`). Для них пришлось писать собственный велосипед такого вида:

```
[ContentProperty("Arguments")]
[DefaultProperty("Value")]
public class StringFormat : InvisibleHelperElement
{
    static List<DependencyProperty> InlineArgProperties;

    static StringFormat()
    {
        InlineArgProperties = new List<DependencyProperty>()
            { Arg0Property, Arg1Property, /*9 штук*/ };
        // на самом деле тут страшновато выглядящий код с рефлексией
    }

    public StringFormat()
    {
        Arguments = new ObservableCollection<FormatArgument>();
        Arguments.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;
    }

    public string Value
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(string), typeof(StringFormat));

    public object Arg0
    {
        get { return GetValue(Arg0Property); }
        set { SetValue(Arg0Property, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty Arg0Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Arg0", typeof(object), typeof(StringFormat),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(FormatConstants.UnsetArgValue, UpdateValue));

    // тут ещё такие же Arg1, ... Arg9

    public object FallbackValue
    {
        get { return GetValue(FallbackValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FallbackValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FallbackValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("FallbackValue", typeof(object), typeof(StringFormat),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(FormatConstants.UnsetArgValue, UpdateValue));

    public ObservableCollection<FormatArgument> Arguments { get; private set; }

    // Нужно переопределить этот метод, чтобы аргументы воспринимались как
    // логические дочерние элементы
    protected override System.Collections.IEnumerator LogicalChildren
    {
        get { return Arguments.GetEnumerator(); }
    }

    public string Format
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(FormatProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FormatProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FormatProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
                "Format", typeof(string), typeof(StringFormat),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(UpdateValue));

    // этот callback будет вызываться, когда список аргументов обновится.
    // добавляет/убирает аргументы в визуальное дерево, подписывается/отписывается
    // от их изменений
    void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewItems != null)
            foreach (object item in e.NewItems)
            {
                var formatArg = item as FormatArgument;
                if (formatArg == null)
                    continue;
                AddLogicalChild(formatArg);
                AddVisualChild(formatArg);
                formatArg.PropertyChanged += OnArgumentChanged;
            }

        if (e.OldItems != null)
            foreach (object item in e.OldItems)
            {
                var formatArg = item as FormatArgument;
                if (formatArg == null)
                    continue;
                formatArg.PropertyChanged -= OnArgumentChanged;
                RemoveVisualChild(formatArg);
                RemoveLogicalChild(formatArg);
            }

        UpdateValue();
    }

    // этот callback вызывается когда изменяется какой-либо из аргументов.
    // обновляет результат
    void OnArgumentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateValue();
    }

    object[] GatherParams()
    {
        var inlineArgs =
            InlineArgProperties.Select(p => GetValue(p))
                               .TakeWhile(v => v != FormatConstants.UnsetArgValue)
                               .ToList();
        var contentArgs = Arguments.Select(arg => arg.Value).ToList();
        return inlineArgs.Concat(contentArgs).ToArray();
    }

    void UpdateValue()
    {
        if (Format != null)
        {
            try
            {
                Value = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, Format, GatherParams());
                return;
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
            }
        }
        Value = (FallbackValue != FormatConstants.UnsetArgValue && FallbackValue != null) ?
                    FallbackValue.ToString() : null;
    }
}

public class FormatArgument : InvisibleHelperElement, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public object Value
    {
        get { return GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Value", typeof(object), typeof(FormatArgument),
            new PropertyMetadata(
                FormatConstants.UnsetArgValue,
                (o, args) => ((FormatArgument)o).NotifyPropertyChanged()));

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void NotifyPropertyChanged()
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(ValueProperty.Name));
    }
}

public class InvisibleHelperElement : FrameworkElement
{
    static InvisibleHelperElement()
    {
        WidthProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(InvisibleHelperElement), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0));
        HeightProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(InvisibleHelperElement), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0));
        FocusableProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(InvisibleHelperElement), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false));
    }
}

static class FormatConstants
{
    static public readonly object UnsetArgValue = new object();
}
```

Использовать так:

```
<h:StringFormat Name="LicenseUpdatePromptText"
    Format="{DynamicResource ID_DEAR_USERNAME_UPDATE_YOUR_WHATEVER}"
    Arg0="{Binding Username}"
    Arg1="{DynamicResource ID_ACTIVATION_KEY}"/>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, ElementName=LicenseUpdatePromptText}"/>
```

Ещё одна проблема — как передать составную локализованную строку из VM в View, для этого тоже пришлось писать довольно обширный велосипед.